House wiring - potential risks
I bought my house roughly 4 years ago, and although it was in a good state of repair, at least aesthetically, there were a few improvements/ adjustments I knew I'd like to make at some point in the future when I moved in.
Having made some of the smaller improvements over my time here so far, one thing that became apparent very early on was that I would probably need to replace the distribution board - and over the last few years, I have identified some more electrical improvements which need addressing - things like: additional sockets installed in most of the rooms, electric shower replacement, kitchen extractor fan replacement, installation of bathroom extractor fan, etc. I am also looking into a potential solar installation.
Over the last couple of weeks, I have had a few of electricians come to survey the work I want doing, and provide quotes. The thing that's stood out to me when showing them the work I'd like done, is how they have all been astounded at how the electrics are currently set up.
It appears that the whole house is running on only 3 circuits - upstairs and downstairs lighting on one each, and then everything else on the third, including sockets, all kitchen appliances (fridge/ freezer, washing machine, dishwasher), etc.
The last electrician queried if I had noticed any problems with the electrics because of this, and generally speaking - I haven't. I've not had the circuits trip at all since being here. I am obviously looking into having additional circuits installed as part of the electrical work I will get done, and potentially having the house fully re-wired, but I'm curious - as someone who knows very little about electrics - what are the potential issues/ dangers with the way that the house is currently wired?
In case it's useful information - I'm in the UK, and the house was built in the 1960s - I suspect that the current distribution board & wiring is all what was originally installed when the house was built. The household would probably be classed as low usage - only two of us living here, although I work from home most of the time, so electric usage is fairly consistent throughout the day.

I'm not very familiar with wiring in UK homes. However it sounds as if the home is wired so as to have the high possibility of overdrawn circuits. The result can be an inconvenience or a disaster such as a fire. Adding additional outlets and such could exacerbate that. The telling factor here is the reaction of all of the techs that observed the home. Astonishment from a number (all) of the electricians should bring concerne. The exact "why" is really not as important as correcting the issue. Choose a company and have the wiring brought up to current standards. That would be the wise and prude

Your question is rather vague. You haven't provided much detail about your hardware, so assessing "risk" is difficult. Please see [ask], then see if you can refine (and simplify) your question to ask something more specific.

You have had 3 professionals physically look at it. Follow their advice.  Why would you ask random strangers instead?

@crip659, a UK socket circuit of that age will almost certainly be a 30A ring circuit, which (at 240V) allows for 4x power use compared to a US 15A, 120V circuit. Appliance leads are protected by the fuse in the plug. As most (non-heating) loads are now more efficient than their 1960s predecessors, I wouldn't expect problems from this setup.

You have 3 circuits?  And they're 240V?  That sounds pretty luxe.  My winter cottage is in the territory ceded to America by the Mexican Cession, and it only has 2 circuits, and they're 120V.  Spanish electrical codes shrug

@RohitGupta If you read my question, you'll see I am planning on following their advice - the question is about what the risks are.

I too am not familiar with homes in the UK but electrical usage was probably the same as in the USA back in the 60's. Bedrooms had a light and an electric clock/radio. living rooms had a few lamps a clock and maybe a TV and HIFI. bathrooms had a fan and an outlet for an electric razor, no hair dryers back then. Kitchens had a refrig, toaster and maybe an electric percolator. Back then, three circuits would have been enough for a house. Wiring in the 60's had become fairly advanced by then and fusing/circuit breakers was a science. If your usage is low, you shouldn't expect any major problems. If you do overload a circuit the fuse or breaker will operate and keep things safe. The fact that you haven't experienced any problems would imply that you haven't exceeded the loading of your system. Adding circuits would be required if you will be increasing your usage or if you are renovating rooms to bring them up to your codes.

There's nothing inherently risky about having only three circuits in a home, but it might be evidence that other risky things are present. Your home was built recently enough that I would consider that unlikely, but there's not enough information in your question to be sure.
Where I am in the US, lots of houses were built with knob and tube wiring, which took the form of sort of a web running through the house. The wires are held fast in the 'knobs', and the hot & neutral wires are separated and often not visually distinct. Splices were made using solder and then covered by the wall. As a result, modern retrofitters often save money by using a portion of the knob & tube system and connecting it to the main panel with new wiring. Each circuit created in this way needs to be isolated from the others, and the webbish nature of knob & tube wiring makes that a difficult job. So they use as few circuits as they can get away with. In fact this was exactly the case with the home I currently live in; when we purchased it the entire upstairs was on a single circuit. This kind of lazy retrofit often comes with other lazy choices which can add some small risk. So if your home's electrical system shows evidence of being retrofitted, this setup might be evidence of potential risk.
Even if it's not a retrofit, you're potentially running a lot of power through that single circuit. One thing to check is the size of the circuit breaker on your one large circuit compared to the size of the wires it supplies. My limited knowledge of UK standards are that a typical circuit is going to be rated at 32 amps. A typical home can easily draw more than 32 amps at once. If the circuit breaker is rated higher than this, but the wires are not sized up, then there is a danger that the wires overheat  instead of tripping the breaker when this happens. Overheating wires can eventually lead to sparks and risk of fire.
But the electricians didn't say anything about this, right? Just questions of convenience? In that case, assuming your breaker and wires are properly sized, this is just an issue of convenience. For instance, it would likely be pretty easy to trip the breaker if you are cooking, running the dishwasher, doing clothes, etc., all at once. If you have an issue with the wiring it will be that much harder to isolate the cause. But otherwise not unsafe.
